# Does CGLib modify all instances of a class

Tags: java, cglib

If I implemented some MethodInterceptor as below:

```
public class HashCodeAlwaysZeroMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

  public Object intercept(Object object, Method method, Object[] args,
    MethodProxy methodProxy) throws Throwable {

    if ("hashCode".equals(method.getName())) {

      return 0;
    }

    return methodProxy.invokeSuper(object, args);
  }
}

Object proxy = Enhancer.create(
  Object.class,
  new HashCodeAlwaysZeroMethodInterceptor());
```

Is every instance of Object now enhanced? IE: if i do something like:

```
class foo { foo(){} }
foo myfoo = new foo();
int hash = myfoo.hashCode();
System.io.println(hash); //Prints 0
```

Will it indeed print 0?

Answer (score 0):

From API DOCS

create

```
public static Factory create(java.lang.Class type,
                             Callback callback)
```

> Helper method to create an intercepted object. For finer control over
>   the generated instance, use a new instance of Enhancer instead of this
>   static method.

```
Parameters:
    type - class to extend or interface to implement
    callback - the callback to use for all methods
```

From the docs it seems answer to your question is yes

Comment: It still doesn't look clear to me. create() seems to return a factory that can be used to instantiate enhanced objects... meaning you have to explicitly instantiate them yourself